# Should I always mutate the offspring in steady-state selection?

Tags: selection, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Having read the pseudocode for implementing steady-state selection in Genetic Algorithms in [Essentials of Metaheuristics](http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/) and this [site](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~neal.holts/dga/optimizationAlgorithms/steadyStateGA.html),
should I always mutate the children or I should subject it to a mutation probability, say 50%?

I was a bit worried that population will not converge if I always do mutation at each generation, because the chromosomes are represented by real number values from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of a **Genetic Algorithm** is very sensible with respect to the weight values that you heuristically choose.

The probability values assigned to each action really *depend on* the particular genetic scheme that you are applying, the way in which data is *represented* and *affected* by *mutation* and *crossover*, the initial population and the problem itself.

So, in order to *heuristically* choose the *best* weight values for your problem, I advice you to keep track of the following data:

- the *evolution* of the **Entropic Diversity Index** (ref: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index)) of your population as time goes by
- the *evolution* of the **best fitness function** value within your population as time goes by
- the *evolution* of the **average fitness function** value within your population as time goes by
- the **rate** of *new individuals* that appear with the same *genetic code* as *existing (or past) individuals*

Here I attach a plot which shows the evolution of these parameters in one of the earliest executions *(I still had to balance it out)* of **AGER**, a custom-made *genetic algorithm* that is capable of automatically finding the best approximation of the ideal design of an *embedded microprocessor* based on the *simplescalar architecture* for executing a given application.

[image]
[(click to enlarge picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOyZb.png)

Ideally, you want to set your weight values so that the initial *slope is as low as possible*, but not up to a point that *average fitness function* value doesn't improve along several generations *(it should be allowed to temporarily worsen, though)*. The *diversity* should be kept relatively high as long as possible, while the average value of the fitness function should be grow very slowly *(unlike in the picture)*. The *best fitness value*, instead, should verified to be a *monotonically increasing* function.

---

Having said this, a rate of mutation equal to `50%` seems to be very high.